# Novel: Incarnated Master-Swordsman is on a Quest to find his Love and save His Homeland

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

I wasn’t able to find this novel since I've read it as a child/teenager at least 10 years ago, but more like 15.

The story goes somewhat like this:
A boy escapes the siege of his father’s castle. His family gets killed and he decides to travel as far away as he can. He meets a band of thieves and joins them. In their travel he somehow learns he is the Incarnation of a master swordsman and his quest is to find a girl which is also the Inkarnation of His Love. Somehow he find's her at a big caravan. He learns that they together need to find and save their original Homeland.

Comment: What do they need to find? I think it got cut off.

Comment: They need to find their Homeland - it's a long lost City or something like that. Sry i wrote this text by phone last night :/

Comment: Sounds a little bit like Magician by Ray Feist (http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/book-synopsis/magician) but that book is almost 40 years old and I don't remember a caravan.

Comment: sadly not :( but the story is kinda similar to this one... thanks for answering :)